# Why is the svg in my logo div pushing my navigation out of my header

Tags: html, css, svg

Title says it all, my svg logo div with the iframe in it is pushing down my navigation on the right side of my webpage. I don't understand why it is doing that, so I am here to see if I can find some guidance. As always all help is appreciated.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css"/>
<title></title>
</head>
<body>

<Header>
<div id="logo"><iframe src="img/logo/caseywoelfle.com.svg" width="150" height="76" frameborder="none"></iframe></div>
<nav>
<ul>
<li><a href="index.html">home</a></li>
<li><a href="about.html">about me</a></li>
<li><a href="portfolio.html">portfolio</a></li>
<li><a href="blog.html">blog</a></li>
<li><a href="contact.html">contact</a></li>
</ul>
</nav>
</Header>

<div id="homepage">
<div id="banner-h">
<p id="bht">

</p>
</div>

</div>

<footer>
<span id="fom">
<h1>find out more about me</h1>
</span>
</footer>

</body>
</html>

body {
width: 100%;
background: #444444; }

/*Header styles*/
header {
width: 100%;
height: 77px;
background: #ffffff; }
header nav {
height: 100%;
vertical-align: middle;
float: right;
margin-right: 60px; }
header nav #logo {
width: 150px;
margin-left: 60px;
float: left; }
header nav ul {
list-style-type: none;
margin: 0;
padding: 0; }
header nav li {
height: 100%;
line-height: 77px;
display: inline-block;
margin-left: 55px; }
header nav a {
color: #000000;
text-decoration: none;
text-transform: uppercase; }

/*Homepage Styles*/
#homepage {
width: 100%;
background: #444444; }
#homepage #banner-h {
margin-top: 56px;
height: 751px;
background: #ffffff; }
#homepage #banner-h #bht {
height: 88px;
margin: auto;
color: #000000; }

footer {
margin-top: 56px;
background: #ffffff;
width: 100%;
height: 166px; }
footer #fom {
height: 90%;
text-align: center;
display: table;
width: 100%; }
footer h1 {
display: table-cell;
vertical-align: middle; }

/*# sourceMappingURL=style.css.map */
```

Comment: Would you be able to provide screenshots or a demo (e.g. on jsfiddle?)

Comment: Here is the page with the svg http://imgur.com/zXtxW5n,Y5Vaip1

Comment: here it is without http://imgur.com/G34Lej0

Comment: looks like the logo is occupying the full width of the page. Let me put your css into a demo

Comment: oh...may I ask why you are using an iframe instead of a normal img?

Comment: Because it is an svg, you cant use regular img tag for that, at least as far as I know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you have is because your iframe is taking up the whole row, so the menu is pushed down.

You can add this bit of CSS `#logo {display:inline-block;}` to make the iframe act like an inline element (so everything can co-exists on the same line, much like these words you are reading). Then all you have to do is to ensure your `nav` element is narrow enough to fit onto the page (or else it will be pushed down because there isn't enough space). This [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/pnjyudkv/) should explain it better.

Also of note, you CAN have an SVG without an iframe. Take a look at this website I am developing (http://yamichi.me/tour.php), the logo in the page is an SVG tag and it is not in an iframe. This [page](http://seesparkbox.com/foundry/a_bit_about_svg) has more information on using SVG.

For small images, I'd suggest using a PNG instead, as it does not affect loading time much, and has much better support in browsers.

Comment: I attempted to execute the same thing with an image tag that had its width and height set to 150, 76. I also set the nav to take up 40% of the header, and it is still not functioning correctly. The logo div itself is also set to 150px width. So I don't understand how the svg could possibly be taking up the whole header.

Comment: Did you add the CSS to make the logo `display:inline-block;`?

Comment: Yes I did, still getting the issue.

Comment: I re looked through my code, it was just me being an idiot. I was targeting #logo using header nav #logo{} and it wasn't inside of the nav. -_- Thanks for the help your sollution worked.